# Algorithm/data structure to throttle requests

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, throttling

I have a request interface that's called many times a second and looks roughly like this:

```
def do_something(timestamp_in_ms)
```

I'm looking for a way to do a simple request throttling that ensures only the first N requests in a second are handled, and the rest are dropped. This should ideally hold for every time interval that lasts a second (e.g. 00:00:00.123-00:00:01.123) instead of only clock seconds (e.g. 00:00:00-00:00:01).

An addition concern is that `do_something` is called extremely frequently, so throttling must be performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **queue** that holds the timestamps of previous N-1 requests, and compares the timestamp of a new candidate request with the timestamp of the earliest request in the queue.

- if the difference is more than one second, the candidate request is carried out and its timestamp added to queue;
- if the difference is less than one second, the candidate request is thrown out.

Whenever a new timestamp is added to the queue, the oldest timestamp is thrown out.

Resources:

- [Wikipedia on Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type))
- [Python documentation on module `queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Comment: I'd suppose what conceptually is a queue here should actually be implemented as a ring buffer?

Comment: @ZizhengTai I don't think that really matters. You can use any implementation of a queue. If you like ring buffers you can use a ring buffer. Python already has classes `queue.Queue` and `queue.SimpleQueue` so I suggest using one of these, unless you specifically want the learning opportunity of implementing your own.